# duende identity server 6.2 session managment

Tags: identityserver4, session-management, duende-identity-server

I had indetity server4 and I had to add session management. I upgrated the application version to duende identityserver 6.2. And created a database based on `PersistedGrantDbContext` and `ConfigurationDbContext`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqu4E.png)

my database asp .NET core identity Users
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6os8t.png)

my configurations
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwrVn.png)

Now I get a token using `connect/token`
and the token is valid.
But now sessions are not saved to the `ServerSideSessions` and Devices table in the `DeviceCodes` table.

How do me added saving sissions and devices in my database?
To add management using interface `ISessionManagementService`?
Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add codes as text (instead on images) in the questions/answers please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What flow are you trying to use? authorization code flow or device flow?

Comment: I hope that you added this extension method on startup/program `.AddServerSideSessions()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to implement your session management logic.
Step 1
Create a UserSessions table, then when the user gets an accessToken save the session to that table.
Step 2
When you need to delete a session, you give the records from the PersistedGrants table and delete the corresponding sessions.
But there is one drawback to this implementation:
A user's session will only die when their accessToken expires.